# Clicking button causes quick zoom in and out

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Sometimes when I click on a button in an Excel spreadsheet I've created, when I release the button, the worksheet quickly zooms in and out. There isn't anything in the VBA code to tell it to do it and it doesn't happen every time.

[Weird zoom thing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMLIb.gif)

Here's the code:

```
Sub CopyCellR1()

Dim Sh As Shape
    With ActiveSheet
        For Each Sh In .Shapes
            If Not Intersect(Sh.TopLeftCell, .Range("A1:C1")) Is Nothing Then
            Sh.Select
            With Selection.Font

        .ColorIndex = 1

        End With
        End If
    Next Sh
    End With

      Dim c As Object
      Set c = ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller)
      c.Select
      With Selection.Font
      .ColorIndex = 5

   End With

    Dim r As Range
    Set r = ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell
        Range(Cells(r.Row, r.Column), Cells(r.Row, r.Column)).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Range("E1").Select
        ActiveCell.PasteSpecial

End Sub
```

Any help will be great.
Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? What research have you done? Where have you got stuck? [superuser.com/help/how-to-ask](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: This code doesn't have has command to Zoom in & Out,, better [Edit] your post & attach the GIF for the Sheet, help us to understand the issue!!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It seems to be some kind of problem with the sheet being zoomed out too much (only to 80%). When I zoomed in to 100% the problem went away.